# Identify multiple instances of my custom visual - on same tab or across tabs

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a custom Power BI visual that stores some information in local storage. This works fine as long as user has only one instance of my visual.

On multiple instances of same visual, I am unable to identify which visual is accessing local storage.

Is there any way, I can assign a unique identifier to each instance? or at least get tab on which my instance is placed.